# Android - centering Button inside an HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to create a kind of image gallery by using a `HorizontalScrollView`.
I would like to have a button centered vertically, but even tho I specify the `gravity` as `center_vertical` in my button, there's no way to make it work, since it always sticks to the top.
Here's my layout:

```
        <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/cameraPlaceholderHeight">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/greyBackgroundColor"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/take_picture_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/take_picture_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/take_picture_rounded_button"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/syi_camera_active"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set your linear layout's height to match_parent

Comment: thanks a lot, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

On your LinearLayout inside the HorizontalScrollView, use

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

instead of

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

A mock-up screen would really help to find out what you want exactly. Anyway, from your layout I could understand that, you need to put a camera button in the centre of your `HorizontalScrollView`.

In that case you might think of wrapping your horizontal scrollview with a `RelativeLayout` like the example below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <!-- Other items here --> 
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_blue"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_blue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `android:fillViewport="true"` in Your both scroll view

Answer (score 0):

set the LinearLayout inside the HorizontalScrollView like that:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/camera_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

the result:

[image: Button Centered Vertically]

BTW: you can get rid of the android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" attribute in your Button.